# Issues in saving document using Polymerfire

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, polymerfire

I'm trying to save data into firebase database but always run into TypeError. Can't seem to find what the issue is. Here is my `<template>` code:

```
<firebase-auth
    id="auth"
    app-name="notes"
    provider="google"
    signed-in="{{signedIn}}"
    user="{{user}}">
</firebase-auth>

<firebase-document
    id="document"
    app-name="notes"
    path="[[editableNoteId]]"
    data="{{editableNote}}">
</firebase-document>

<na-editor
    id="editor"
    note="{{editableNote}}"
    on-close="commitChange">
</na-editor>
```

Script:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'note-app',

    behaviors: [Polymer.NoteAppBehavior],

    signIn: function() {
      this.$.auth.signInWithPopup();
    },

    get notesPath() {
      return '/notes/' + this.user.uid;
    },

    toEditableId: function(noteId) {
      return this.notesPath + '/' + noteId;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: this.$.document.save is not a function. (In 'this.$.document.save(this.notesPath)', 'this.$.document.save' is undefined)
```

NOTE: The app-name and firebase-app have been defined correctly.

Comment: I am also trying from android app but nothing happen same code was working today when i go to console the database is not loading may be their servers down or something else happen

Answer (score 3):

In version `0.11.0` the `save()` method was renamed to `saveValue()` to maintain compatibility with certain JS compilers and older browsers. See [the release notes](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/releases/tag/v0.11.0) for details.

The [docs](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/firebase/polymerfire/firebase-document) are now also showing the update, but may not have been when you looked at them.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved the issue. It was updated 4 days ago so I guess I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the script fixed the issue.

```
save: function() {      
    this.$.document.saveValue();
},
```